# Enter different date formats, datepicker

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datepicker

I have the following code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.sv.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/Scripts/datareview.datatablestools.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.hospital_datepicker_From').datepicker({
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                extraFormats: ["dd.mm.yy", "ddmmYYYY", "ddmmyy", "yyyymmdd"],
                startDate: "2011-01-01",
                language: "sv"
            });

            $('.hospital_datepicker_To').datepicker({
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                extraFormats: ["dd.mm.yy", "ddmmYYYY", "ddmmyy","yyyymmdd"],
                startDate: "2011-01-01",
                language: "sv"
            });

   updateMinToDate = function () {

            var toDate = $('.hospital_datepicker_To').datepicker('getDate');
            var fromDate = $('.hospital_datepicker_From').datepicker('getDate');


            if (toDate < fromDate) {
                $('.hospital_datepicker_To').datepicker('update', '');
            }

            $('.hospital_datepicker_To').datepicker('setStartDate', fromDate);
        };

      clearDatePopover = function () {

            $("#toDate").popover("hide");
        }
```

Here Is my HTML:

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" id="fromDate" name="FromDate" onchange="updateMinToDate(); clearDatePopover();" class="form-control hospital_datepicker_From" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD" value="@(Model.StatisticHospitalFilter.FromDate.HasValue ? Model.StatisticHospitalFilter.FromDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty)" required />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">t.o.m.</span>
                                <input type="text" id="toDate" name="ToDate" class="form-control hospital_datepicker_To" autocomplete="off" onchange="clearDatePopover();"placeholder="ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD" value="@(Model.StatisticHospitalFilter.ToDate.HasValue ? Model.StatisticHospitalFilter.ToDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty)" required />
                            </div>
```

I want to allow different formats to be entered In the datepicker, but I can't get It work.

When I enter a date In the format yyyymmdd, It just selects today's date, instead of the date that I entered In the format above.

How can I allow different date formats to be entered?

Comment: Were you ever able to get different date formats to work?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem possible with datepicker bootstrap. You have to put slash between your numbers when you enter a date.

Also how would datepicker make difference between your extraformats ["ddmmYYYY", "ddmmyy", "yyyymmdd"] and find which number is day, month or year ?

This could help however : http://bit.ly/1Zxstek